# How to draw diagrams using draw2d?

Tags: eclipse, graphics, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I have designed a meta model for my systems, and I want to create a graphical editor to facilitate the creation of a model. For this, I'm using the GEF editor. I have failed to come across any easy to understand tutorial on how to draw diagrams using draw2d and then implement then using editparts etc from the GEF.

Can anyone suggest me any useful resources for the same. Video tutorials would ofcourse be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

GEF is the graphical framework developed on top of draw2d and SWT Tree .

Here is Step by Step tutorial creation of graphical editor on a POJO model and same can be used for EMF model or any other domain model

Url : http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ip/resources/GEF/GEF_Tutorial_2up.pdf

List of resources for GEF :  [Tutorials](http://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF/Articles,_Tutorials,_Slides)

Hope this is helpful !!